# Delphi JNI Event handler

Tags: android, delphi, java-native-interface, firemonkey

I have an Android SDK which defines an abstract interface for receiving events and a class that is passed to the events:

```java
package com.imagpay;

public class SwipeEvent
{
  public static int TYPE_DISCONNECTED = 1;
  public static int TYPE_CONNECTED = 2;
  public static int TYPE_STARTED = 3;
  public static int TYPE_STOPPED = 4;
  public static int TYPE_READDATA = 5;
  public static int TYPE_PARSEDATA = 6;
  public static int TYPE_IC_INSERTED = 7;
  public static int TYPE_IC_REMOVED = 8;
  private int a;
  private String b;
  private Object c;

  public SwipeEvent(Object paramObject, int paramInt, String paramString)
  {
    this.c = paramObject;
    this.a = paramInt;
    this.b = paramString;
  }

  public Object getSource()
  {
    return this.c;
  }

  public int getType()
  {
    return this.a;
  }

  public String getValue()
  {
    return this.b;
  }
}
```

```java
package com.imagpay;

public abstract interface SwipeListener
{
  public abstract void onDisconnected(SwipeEvent paramSwipeEvent);

  public abstract void onConnected(SwipeEvent paramSwipeEvent);

  public abstract void onStarted(SwipeEvent paramSwipeEvent);

  public abstract void onStopped(SwipeEvent paramSwipeEvent);

  public abstract void onReadData(SwipeEvent paramSwipeEvent);

  public abstract void onParseData(SwipeEvent paramSwipeEvent);

  public abstract void onICDetected(SwipeEvent paramSwipeEvent);
}
```

I converted them to Delphi using Java2Pas:

```pascal
unit com.imagpay.SwipeEvent;

interface

uses
  AndroidAPI.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes;

type
  {Class forward declarations}
  JSwipeEvent = interface; {com/imagpay/SwipeEvent}

  JSwipeEventClass = interface(JObjectClass)
    ['{6C6C07D9-F191-47A5-AFF0-E0EEE9CD8903}']
    {Property methods}
    function _GetTYPE_CONNECTED: Integer;
    procedure _SetTYPE_CONNECTED(Value: Integer);
    function _GetTYPE_DISCONNECTED: Integer;
    procedure _SetTYPE_DISCONNECTED(Value: Integer);
    function _GetTYPE_IC_INSERTED: Integer;
    procedure _SetTYPE_IC_INSERTED(Value: Integer);
    function _GetTYPE_IC_REMOVED: Integer;
    procedure _SetTYPE_IC_REMOVED(Value: Integer);
    function _GetTYPE_PARSEDATA: Integer;
    procedure _SetTYPE_PARSEDATA(Value: Integer);
    function _GetTYPE_READDATA: Integer;
    procedure _SetTYPE_READDATA(Value: Integer);
    function _GetTYPE_STARTED: Integer;
    procedure _SetTYPE_STARTED(Value: Integer);
    function _GetTYPE_STOPPED: Integer;
    procedure _SetTYPE_STOPPED(Value: Integer);
    {Methods}
    function init(Param0: JObject; Param1: Integer; Param2: JString): JSwipeEvent; cdecl;
    {Properties}
    property TYPE_CONNECTED: Integer read _GetTYPE_CONNECTED write _SetTYPE_CONNECTED;
    property TYPE_DISCONNECTED: Integer read _GetTYPE_DISCONNECTED write _SetTYPE_DISCONNECTED;
    property TYPE_IC_INSERTED: Integer read _GetTYPE_IC_INSERTED write _SetTYPE_IC_INSERTED;
    property TYPE_IC_REMOVED: Integer read _GetTYPE_IC_REMOVED write _SetTYPE_IC_REMOVED;
    property TYPE_PARSEDATA: Integer read _GetTYPE_PARSEDATA write _SetTYPE_PARSEDATA;
    property TYPE_READDATA: Integer read _GetTYPE_READDATA write _SetTYPE_READDATA;
    property TYPE_STARTED: Integer read _GetTYPE_STARTED write _SetTYPE_STARTED;
    property TYPE_STOPPED: Integer read _GetTYPE_STOPPED write _SetTYPE_STOPPED;
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/imagpay/SwipeEvent')]
  JSwipeEvent = interface(JObject)
    ['{BD54986A-FE87-416E-9ED2-468DBE5B2827}']
    {Methods}
    function getSource: JObject; cdecl;
    function getType: Integer; cdecl;
    function getValue: JString; cdecl;
  end;

  TJSwipeEvent = class(TJavaGenericImport<JSwipeEventClass, JSwipeEvent>)
  end;

implementation

const
  TYPE_DISCONNECTED = 1;
  TYPE_CONNECTED = 2;
  TYPE_STARTED = 3;
  TYPE_STOPPED = 4;
  TYPE_READDATA = 5;
  TYPE_PARSEDATA = 6;
  TYPE_IC_INSERTED = 7;
  TYPE_IC_REMOVED = 8;

end.
```

```pascal
unit com.imagpay.SwipeListener;

interface

uses
  AndroidAPI.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  com.imagpay.SwipeEvent;

type
  {Class forward declarations}
  JSwipeListener = interface; {com/imagpay/SwipeListener}

  JSwipeListenerClass = interface(IJavaClass)
    ['{E528660F-D406-406F-8655-FFB76A64B3EA}']
  end;

  [JavaSignature('com/imagpay/SwipeListener')]
  JSwipeListener = interface(IJavaInstance)
    ['{51112FBC-8B83-46DC-9C9E-F97837120D06}']
    {Methods}
    procedure onConnected(Param0: JSwipeEvent); cdecl;
    procedure onDisconnected(Param0: JSwipeEvent); cdecl;
    procedure onICDetected(Param0: JSwipeEvent); cdecl;
    procedure onParseData(Param0: JSwipeEvent); cdecl;
    procedure onReadData(Param0: JSwipeEvent); cdecl;
    procedure onStarted(Param0: JSwipeEvent); cdecl;
    procedure onStopped(Param0: JSwipeEvent); cdecl;
  end;

  TJSwipeListener = class(TJavaGenericImport<JSwipeListenerClass, JSwipeListener>)
  end;

implementation

end.
```

How can I use those events in my Delphi code? Those events are used for connectivity with the SDK, and are essential to getting data.

Comment: You imported the listener interface, but where is the code for the other SDK classes that actually fire events to the listener?  On the Delphi side, you would derive a class that implements the listener interface, but then you need to pass an instance of that class to something on the SDK side, and that something is missing in this question.

Comment: This is the class which calls addSwipeListener(JSwipeListener):

Comment: What class are you referring to? There is no `addSwipeListener()` in the code you have shown.

Comment: see it on Embarcadero forum as there is no space here to write the code here.